# ">" В CSS - Что это и для чего это?

Tags: css

Вот есть условный код и я не очень понимаю, что делает и для чего нужен знак сравнения(или как он еще называется). Подскажите для чего он используется или если у "этого" есть название, дайте сурс или доки, где можно прочитать именно про это, пожалуйста.

```
.neon > img{
    
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors Пролистай до комбинаторов и там найдешь то что нужно

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая штука в CSS как [комбинаторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B), они позволяют создавать комбинации [селекторов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B).

Например, у вас есть `<ul class="green">`-список с вложенным `<ul>`-списком, цвет фона текста которого зелёный:

```css
.green li span {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<ul class="green">
  <li><span>1.</span></li>
  <li><span>2.</span></li>
  <li><span>3.</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>3.1.</span></li>
      <li><span>3.2.</span></li>
      <li><span>3.3.</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>4.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Вы хотите сделать так, чтобы только первый уровень `<li>` имел зелёный фон, для этого используйте [комбинатор дочерних элементов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) (`>`):

```css
.green > li > span {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<ul class="green">
  <li><span>1.</span></li>
  <li><span>2.</span></li>
  <li><span>3.</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>3.1.</span></li>
      <li><span>3.2.</span></li>
      <li><span>3.3.</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>4.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Если перевести селектор `.green > li > span` в "человеческий", то CSS видит это следующим образом: `взять класс green, взять только дочерний li первого уровня вложенности, взять только дочерний span первого уровня вложенности`.

---

К слову, `.green li span` - это тоже комбинатор, называется [комбинатор потомков](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator).

Comment: Хорошо объяснил (+)